# ImpRec invalid thunks seem valid

Tags: debugging, iat

I have been rebuilding the IAT for an executable and have used ImpRec though some of the thunks are showing up as invalid even though on the apparent they show the `rva`, `mod`, `ord` and `name` fields just like the valid thunks.

Should I just delete the thunks which are highlighted as invalid or do further analysis and if so how ?

[image]

Comment: It could be because Import REConstructor detected thunks for 2 different DLLs without a 0x00000000 separator entry between the thunks. Could you please post a screenshot?

Comment: No it's not that I checked in OllyDbg

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that. Your screenshot confirms it :)
See my answer below @ http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/6135/1562

Answer (score 3):

Import REConstructor detected thunks for 2 different DLLs (`combase.dll` and `ole32.dll`) without a `0x00000000` separator entry between the thunks. This is because one of these DLLs (`ole32.dll`) exports functions that are forwarded to the other DLL (`combase.dll`).

Import REConstructor needs all adjacent thunks (without a `0x00000000` in between them) to be from the same DLL, so to fix this problem, you'll need to double-click on each of those `combase.dll` thunks and specify the forwarding function from `ole32.dll`.

For example, double-click on the `combase.dll!CLSIDFromString` entry and tell Import REConstructor that its Import Table entry should actually be `ole32.dll!CLSIDFromString`, then double-click on the `combase.dll!CLSIDFromProgID` entry and tell Import REConstructor that its Import Table entry should actually be `ole32.dll!CLSIDFromProgID`, then the same for `CoTaskMemFree`, `CreateStreamOnHGlobal`, etc. Note that you'll need to do this for all `combase.dll` thunks in this block, not just the ones that are currently highlighted as invalid.

Comment: It works though what should I do in the case of user32.dll which has one function forwarded to another dll, it would be tedious to manually change the 162 other functions in user32.dll, is there no other way around this?

Comment: @user28130  what was your solution for this problem?