# ImpRec invalid NtdllDefWindowProc_A seem valid

Tags: debugging, iat, protection

I have a problem that NtdllDefWindowProc_A function from ntdll is
inside user32 thunk.

[image]

Following @Jason Geffner answer in [ImpRec invalid thunks seem valid](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6134/imprec-invalid-thunks-seem-valid) I tried to change it to NtdllDefWindowProc_A from user32, but when I rebuild it after the fix with PE tool the file didn't work at all.

Then I tried again and cut NtdllDefWindowProc_A function from the chunk,
and the rebuild work and the file run without a problem.

its probably not a good idea to cut NtdllDefWindowProc_A from the file....So what did I did wrong?

Thanks you all for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the static import `user32!DefWindowProcA` is getting forwarded to `ntdll!NtdllDefWindowProc_A`.

You need to double-click on the `ntdll!NtdllDefWindowProc_A` entry in Import REConstructor and change it to `user32!DefWindowProcA`.

Comment: Its work! Thanks :-)
How did you know to what name it should be change? command sense with experience? Or do you have a way that I will be able to use to?

Comment: Two ways to tell in this case: 1. The imports listed in your screenshot above are sorted alphabetically. If you look at the exports from `user32.dll`, you'll see `DefWindowProcA` is alphabetically between exports `DeleteMenu` and `DefMDIChildProcA`. 2. The function name `NtdllDefWindowProc_A` sounds like it might be a hook or forwarded-function for `DefWindowProcA`.